# When I change language, I lose my design

Tags: c#, winforms

when i change language and font of my app (en-fr-fa-es)
I lose its design

when I change the font made it problem

```
startlanguage = "Fa";
HelliStaticform.ActiveForm.Font = Bzar;
automaticdeletebutton.Text = "حذف هوشمند";
            filebutton.Text = "بایگانی";
            newproject.Text = "جدید";
            openproject.Text = "بازکردن";
            save.Text = "ذخیره";
            saveas.Text = "ذخیره در";
            pointerbutton.Text = "نشانگر";
            insert.Text = "درج";
            drawlinebutton.Text = "خط";
            drawforcebutton.Text = "نیرو";
            basebutton.Text = "تکیه گاه";
            drawnormalbasebutton.Text = "تکیه گاه ساده";
            drawgradientbasebutton.Text = "تکیه گاه متحرک";
            Horizontalgradientbasebutton.Text = "افقی";
            Verticalgradientbasebutton.Text = "عمودی";
            degreegradientbase.Text = "زاویه دار";
            mirrorbutton.Text = "آینه...";
            editbutton.Text = "ویرایش";
            editbasebutton.Text = "تکیه گاه ها";
            editforcebutton.Text = "نیروها";
            editlinebutton.Text = "خطوط";
            editpointbutton.Text = "نقاط";
            Delete.Text = "پاک کردن";
            clearAllbutton.Text = "پاک کردن همه";
            checkbutton.Text = "آزمایش پایداری";
            solvebutton.Text = "حل";

            solveboxvisible.Text = "شکل تحلیل شده";
            aboutbutton.Text = "درمورد..";
            tableview.Text = "نمای جدولی";
            calculatemenu.Text = "تحلیل";
            Helpmenu.Text = "راهنمایی";
            addcommentoolbox.Text = "توضیح";
```

and

```
startlanguage = "En";
toolStrip1.Font = AmbersHand;
automaticdeletebutton.Text = "Automatic Delete";
            filebutton.Text = "File";
            newproject.Text = "New Project";
            openproject.Text = "Open Project";
            save.Text = "Save";
            saveas.Text = "Save az";
            pointerbutton.Text = "Pointer";
            insert.Text = "Insert";
            drawlinebutton.Text = "Line";
            drawforcebutton.Text = "Force";
            basebutton.Text = "Base";
            drawnormalbasebutton.Text = "fixed hinge";
            drawgradientbasebutton.Text = "roller hinges";
            Horizontalgradientbasebutton.Text = "Horizontal";
            Verticalgradientbasebutton.Text = "Vertical";
            degreegradientbase.Text = "Degree";
            mirrorbutton.Text = "Mirror";
            editbutton.Text = "Edit";
            editbasebutton.Text = "Bases";
            editforcebutton.Text = "Forces";
            editlinebutton.Text = "Lines";
            editpointbutton.Text = "Points";
            Delete.Text = "Delete";
            clearAllbutton.Text = "Delete All";
            checkbutton.Text = "Cheak solvability";
            solvebutton.Text = "Solve";

            solveboxvisible.Text = "Solved picture";
            aboutbutton.Text = "about..";
            tableview.Text = "table";
            calculatemenu.Text = "Analysis";
            Helpmenu.Text = "Help";
            addcommentoolbox.Text = "Comment";
```

:

(my picturebox and toolbox and many texboxes moving when i change the language)

how can i prevent it?

Comment: It could be to do with one of those `AutoSomething` properties. Make them all false and test again.

Comment: please don't use that many ....... which don't help us reading the question. also, it's not clear what is your problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make you form localizable by setting the form's `Localizable` property to `true`. The `Language` property automatically sets to (Default).

2) Drag a `TextBox` control on the form from the toolbox. Change its text to: "Name".

3) Change the form's `Language` property to another language, ie: Italian.

4) Change the textbox's text to "Nome".

5) Continue for each language you want to add localization.

6) Your Form and your controls might need to be resized / layed out differently for each language.

Comment: i change objectsn namas and..... But when i change names, changes lenght of strings and then change my design.......

Comment: Docking and locking have no effect on that, you surely have the `Autosize` property set.

Comment: autosize is enable.... , my proble is'n size... my probem is movement of controls...